# Why is this close-vote audit question not considered 'primarily opinion-based'?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Earlier I failed [this close vote audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9752836).

I voted to close the question with the reason 'primarily opinion based'.  I chose this reason based on the last line of the question (after having read the whole post):

> If the first approach is valid, then which one is preferred?

Whilst I don't feel qualified to pass technical judgement, this looks to me like the epitome of an opinion-soliciting question.

Is this just a case of a borderline audit?  Or I am I really missing something with regards to my understanding of on-topic questions?

Comment: I'm not qualified for a technical judgement either, but it is important not to get hung up on "keywords" in a post and use them as the only criteria to close a question.  Just that 1 sentence does not make it an opinion based question.

Comment: Agreed, and I always read through a whole post before voting, but the whole post is merely asking for opinions (quote: "Is this a valid thing to do in C++?").  But re-reading [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I can see it might fit under '...generally covers...'.

Comment: It's important to note that, if the question was asking for opinions (debatable), it was asking for a very specific and narrow set of them.  Everything was constrained to the context of the code provided.  I'd personally put this on the acceptable side of borderline.  I can see why you feel it's a borderline audit though.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's a good explanation, thank you.  Looking at the answers provided to that question it seems that there is no ambiguity for C++ coders who were easily able to distinguish between opinion or syntax issues. I'm leaning towards skipping those reviews where I don't grok the code...